# Finding the matrix representation of a linear transformation from one subspace to itself

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation given by $T(x) = Ax$, what is the matrix representation of T? Part of me thinks it's $A$, and part of me thinks it's the $n \times n$ identity matrix. I don't really understand matrix representations well enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful.

I suppose that $A$ is a matrix, meaning $A\in\mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ (or other field other than $\mathbb{R}$).

Saying that $Tx = Ax$ and that $T:V\rightarrow V$ implicitly assumes that

1. $m=n$.
2. $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ (because you can only multiply a matrix with a vector with coordinates)

so $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear transformation given by the formula $T(x) = Ax$.

This means that the matrix representation of $T$ **with respect to the standard basis** of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $A$.

Comment: Yes, specifically A is a 3x3 matrix in this instance. Thank you for the answer, that's definitely helped me understand this a bit more :)

Comment: The field doesn’t have to be $\mathbb R$.